# How do I avoid this SVN error in XCode?

Tags: xcode, svn

I have a project that I am working on on two different Macs. I move the source around via an SVN server (the default one that comes with the Mac). Every single time I try to do an update, I get this error:

> SCM Project File Conflict: MyProj.xcodeproj/brianpapa.pbxuser

Is there any way to avoid it? Each time I have to discard my local copy, and then let the project reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following thread of discussion. It is old though.

- http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2004/jan/msg00197.html
- http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2006/Apr/msg00650.html

.pbxuser file stores user's preferences for the project, e.g. window sizes, active build style, file bookmarks, and a few other things.

There is also a default.pbxuser (or something like that) that you could keep in the repository. Any new user opening the project will get those settings as a starting point for their personal .pbxuser file.

Based on this my suggestion would be to include the default preference file only. Else any one changing the user preference settings will result in changes to this file. I guess, it is some non-textual format for storing information and subversion is not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that particular file, but it's quite possible that you didn't need to add that file to Subversion. It looks like it might be a "user settings" file that's local to the machine you're running it on, and each machine can quite happily manage its own file.

If you remove that file from Subversion (save a local copy first if you don't want to delete it completely), then that problem should go away.